# Why dont use the AVX Registers as a ultra fast cache?

Tags: performance, assembly, sse, cpu-registers, avx

I've been wondering why the 16x256 Bit Registers provided by AVX2 aren't getting used for storing normal registers when AVX cant help - to minimize the hitting of cache's for in situations where u just don't happen to have enough registers at hand. IsnÄ't it like that you can set and access AVX Registers in 1-2 Cycles?

All this wouldn't work of course if you're screwing up other code running the AVX stuff and kick it out of the registers. I haven't seen this obvious approach getting used yet, which lead me to asking this question.

Comment: I've wondered this before too. I think it's probably because moving data between general-purpose registers and SSE/AVX registers is slow, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Because AVX2 was just released? And, don't they mask the other registers (e.g. it may be fast to load them, but 64-bit operation will destroy the loaded values)?

Comment: Operations that cross the 128-bit boundary lane are 3 cycles on Sandy Bridge and Haswell. That's slower than a load from L1 cache. And even if there was a way to get some performance out of this, you still need somebody to write the optimization pass for it. (which I doubt is easy)

Comment: Well that would explain it a bit. Anyways, dont they need to double L1 performance again with Broadwell if they implement AVX512? :-) Lets hope we will see some serious improvement in the end of this year.

Comment: @user1610743, Broadwell doesn't have AVX512, it's mostly a compaction of Haswell. The next one should have it.

Comment: gcc started doing it with 4.8 IIRC.

Comment: Yup, I've seen gcc stash stuff away in `xmm0` and then read it back later.

Comment: @Mysticial - loads are 4 cycles in the_ best_ case (longer if using complex addressing, longer if loading to vector regs, etc). You wouldn't generally need to cross the 128-bit boundary as you'd first use the 16 128-bit xmm regs, which have one cycle load/store from GP regs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At one time, Intel indeed recommended spilling from general purpose to SSE registers in their optimization manual. (That's not AVX exactly, but it is the same idea.) I haven't looked at the very latest manuals, so that advice may or may not be out of date.

Spilling to xmm registers has the disadvantage that those registers are not preserved across function calls. Given that the x86-64 is a register-memory machine, accessing spilled values on the stack also requires fewer instructions and fewer registers (compare `add rax, [rsp+k]` to `movq rbx, xmm0/add rax, rbx`). That might go some way to explaining why there isn't much interest in the technique.

Comment: Also with the larger and larger data caches, saving/loading on the stack is 1 cycle.

Comment: Well, L1 cache seems to stick around the same capacity so far. That is what creates the wish for more more more :-)

Comment: Stores to or loads from the stack, or any memory location at all has a minimum latency of 4 cycles, if it hits in L1.